# Facebook on android: unable to login after closeAndClearTokenInformation

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

Hi to all i use Android facebook sdk 3.0.1 and there my login method:

```
public void connect(){

    Session.openActiveSession(HTFacebook.context, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
              if(exception != null){
                  Log.e(TAG,"exception----->" + exception.getMessage());
              }
              if(session.isOpened()){
                  List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                  if(!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)){
                      Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(HTFacebook.context, PERMISSIONS);
                      session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                      return;
                  }
                  MeRequest(session, null, null);
            }
          }
        }); 
}
```

this method let me login correctly, but when i logout i can't login more and facebook gets error (see the attached image)[image]

this is my logout method:

```
public void logout(){

if(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    Session.getActiveSession().close();
    Session.setActiveSession(null);


    this.userInfo=null;
    this.userId=null;
}else{
//already logged out
}
}
```

I want to clear token information because i want to change user. So how i can generate new freshly session that works correctly after closeAndClearTokenInformation()?

PS:if i delete the closeAndClearTokenInformation method all work correctly but i can't change user, also if i login with a differen user from Facebook applicaiton on my application i'm still the old one.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't call both closeAndClearTokenInformation() AND close(). Only one of them. closeAndClearTokenInformation() will already call close() for you.

Comment: @MingLi Same issue, Application crashes coz of throwing : Session made to open already open. And without closeAndClearTokenInformation, I can't change user info.